# VSCode API: Is it possible to change (abbreviate) displayed text?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am thinking of developing a vscode extension that abbreviates variables. I've looked on the official documentation, StackOverflow and the GitHub issues board, but did not manage to find if the following feature is supported. It's likely that I don't know good search terms for it.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to change how the user sees a variable, without it being modified on the code, so the tokenization for syntax highlighting and type inference is preserved. For example, I would like to see `str` instead of `std::string` or a greek letter alpha instead of `rotation_angle`.

Does anyone have any info on whether such feature exists in the VSCode API?

Comment: I'm fairly certain such a feature doesn't exist right now. Considering how many issues the VSCode issue tracker has, there's almost always an unresolved feature request in these cases, but I wasn't able to find one (searching for "IntelliJ" for instance, since it has a feature like this, and feature requests often go like "I'd like to have feature from <other editor>").

Comment: @Gama11, Thank you for having a look. Very useful insight regarding similar feature requests - I didn't think about it that way